# form is published even if the form content is blank when submit and reload the form in flask

Tags: javascript, forms, flask

Flask (1.1.2)

I tried to clear value of form by clicking button "Publish" but I don't know why script is not executing on click.

Java Script is well implemented

```
<script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

But button with argument 'onClick' isn't executing the function 'clear()'

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" onclick="clear()">Publish</button>
```

Form:

```
<div class="entry-con">
    <h1>Write own entry</h1>
    <hr>
    <form method="POST">
        <!-- <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
        </div> -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="note" id="note" placeholder="Content"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" onclick="clear()">Publish</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Main.js:

```
function clear() {
var content = document.getElementById('note')
content.value = ""
console.log()
```

}

views.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash
from flask_login import login_required, login_user, logout_user, current_user
from .models import Note
from . import db


views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        note = request.form.get('note')

        if len(note) < 1:
            flash('Note is too short!', category='error')
        else:
            new_note = Note(data=note, user_id=current_user.id)
            db.session.add(new_note)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Note added!', category='success')

    return render_template("index.html", user=current_user)
```

GitHub Repository: https://github.com/Inexpli/Flask-WebApp

How it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmhJu.png

Comment: Hi Eldzej02 please give us more information about the error you are getting, we are not seeing enough to know the reason behind it. Consider adding the code for `clear()` or the content of your `main.js`

Comment: Your button is type `submit`,  change it to `button` or add the clear function to the form's `onsubmit` method.

Comment: None of the solutions you provided work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution to my problem was just add a redirect function after saving form values, because whenever I was reloading the page, post method still was holding the values ​​of form.

I am still confused that i had to get solution on my own while it is pretty common situation in creating web applications.